# Can't change case of tag "folder" name git

Tags: git, git-tag

I have the following tags:

```
release/1.0
release/2.0
release/2.2.5
Release/2.5.0
Release/3.0.0
```

I want to get the casing to match on  release.  So for example, `release/2.5.0` instead of `Release/2.5.0`.

So I run the following sequence of commands:

```
git tag release/2.5.0 Release/2.5.0
git -d Release/2.5.0
```

However, I end up with (in the above case) `release/2.5.0` being deleted entirely.
I figured that it might be having trouble with the casing (with that being the only difference between the names), so after fetching the tag from my remote, I tried the following:

```
git tag r/2.5.0 Release/2.5.0
git tag -d Release/2.5.0
git tag release/2.5.0 r/2.5.0
```

After this, I have the following tags:

```
r/2.5.0
release/1.0
release/2.0
release/2.2.5
Release/2.5.0
Release/3.0.0
```

So it forced the case of Release back to the original upper case.  I assume a reference being stored somewhere, but I don't know the best way to deal with this.

FWIW: I tried this originally from `cmder` console emulator on Windows and on ubuntu in WSL.  And I tried it in my git GUI client (fork).  The result was the same everywhere.

It's not really a huge deal, but it's a lot less clean, particularly in the git gui when I have two folders dividing my tags between them.

Comment: Git uses, internally, a really terrible "database" to store branch and tag names: there's a flat file, in which upper vs lower case is significant. Then there are individual files in the file system, in which upper vs lower case is significant *on Linux*. But not so much on your system. So Git "thinks" `Release/x` is different from `release/x`, and sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't. Git then partially destroys its own database while updating these "different" names.

Comment: The easy solution for now is to do the renaming on a fully-case-sensitive system: boot up a Linux (in a VM if necessary) and fix it there. Otherwise, well, see the answer you accepted. :-)

Comment: @torek Are you saying that WSL wouldn’t work the same way as a VM for the purposes of this?

Comment: If WSL provides a case-sensitive file system, it should work there. I don't use Windows, hence don't use WSL either, so I have never tried this.

Comment: @torek - I’m pretty sure WSL is for all intents and purposes a Linux os.  So that makes me question whether changing case would work properly on a full Linux distro any differently.  I guess I’ll test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(On this machine I'm using git for windows 2.24.1)**

Since lightweight tags are files/folders in `.git/refs/tags` i cannot have tags with  mixed lower/upper case. Example:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test
$ git tag Release/1.0.0

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test
$ git tag
Release/1.0.0

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test
$ git tag release/2.0

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test
$ git tag
Release/1.0.0
Release/2.0
```

I started off by creating `Release/1.0.0`. Subsequently, if i create `release/2.0` (lower case 'r'), it gets put in the `Release/` folder in `refs/tags`, despite being created as a lower case tag.

Since these are lightweight tags, manipulating the `.git` folder should be safe. Just modify the names of the files and folders to your liking. E.g., after renaming `refs/tags/Release` to `refs/tags/release` i now get lower case tags:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test (old)
$ git tag
release/1.0.0
release/2.0
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thanks!